# Installer will not create a partition labeled D:\

Tags: windows-server-2003, partition, installation

I'm creating a new Windows Server 2003 server through VMWamre (VMWare 8, using VCentre 5.1).

I have connected to an ISO that is on a local disc, and I've got the the setup step where I can create partitions.

My problem is that whenever I create 2x partitions, I'm given C:\ and E:. I want this to be C:\ and D:\, but no matter what I do, I can't get those partitions labeled as such.

Does anybody know how to stop the installer doing this?

Answer (score 6):

The virtual CD/DVD mount point is clearly reserving D:, can you mount an .ISO as a virtual CD/DVD then right click on it in Disk Management, you should be able to change the drive letter it's assigned to - just move it to something other than D: and then try your partitioning action again (although the same trick may work on your existing E:).

Comment: Similar option would be to remove the virtual CD/DVD from the VM, boot it, and create your partitions.  Re-attach the CD/DVD to the VM if needed and it will get assigned the next drive letter.

Comment: @jlehtinen - that doesn't always work unfortunately - and with no W2K3 VMs left any more I don't have the opportunity to test it, I have a horrid feeling that sometimes the drive letter is kept even once it's removed from the VM

Comment: Tested here using Windows Server 2003 VM on ESXi 5.1.  Booted VM with 2 VMDKs and a CD drive (C:, D:, E: respectively).  Shut off VM, removed CD drive, added new VMDK, booted.  Used Disk Management to detect new drive, assigned E: to this.  Powered off VM, added CD drive, booted.  CD drive was assigned F:.   So, it works fine ... but given I had to go into Disk Management to complete this, the method I suggested is less effective/efficient then simply going to Disk Management in the first place.  :)

Comment: @Chopper3 - I figured as much with regard to D:\ being reserved, but I'm not sure where you are meaning for 'Disk Management'? I've never seen this option in VCentre, so pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @jlehtinen - Thanks for the suggestion, which helped me find my solution. In the end did as follows - 1. Create a new VMDK and power it on. 2. Mount the ISO, restart the virtual machine using `Ctrl`, `Alt` + `Ins` so that the Server 2003 installer starts. 3. Create the partitions (initially labeled `C:` and `E:`). 4. Restart the virtual machine once more using `Ctrl`, `Alt` + `Ins`. 5. Once the installer loads again, the partitions already exist from last time and are labeled `C:` and `D:`.

Comment: @DavidGard FYI, 'Disk Management' is the standard Windows utility for viewing/editing disk drives and partitions.  (It's not a VMware tool.)  While in a Windows OS, open it via: Start->run->diskmgmt.msc

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm with you. I was about 12 steps behind at that point so didn't consider it, but I'll have a look in to that as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to those who provided answeers.

In this instance, I followed these steps -

1. Create a new Virtual Machine and power it on.
2. Mount the ISO for Windows Server 2003 (with SP1) and then restart the virtual machine using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> so that the Server 2003 installer starts.
3. Create the partitions to the desired size (they are initially labeled `C:\` and `E:\`).
4. Dismount the ISO and power off the virtual machine.
5. Power the virtual machine on again.
6. Mount the ISO again and then restart the virtual machine using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> so that the Server 2003 installer starts.
7. Once the installer loads again, the partitions already exist from last time and are labeled `C:\` and `D:\`.